# Jetpack Comments Change Placeholder Text

Tags: plugins, filters, comments, javascript, plugin-jetpack

Is there a hook or template file where I can change the placeholder text on the #comment textarea w/in the comment form?

Jetpack loads the form via an iFrame which prevents changing the placeholder text with JS

Please help, thanks!

Similar:

[Placeholders in Jetpack Contact Form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/placeholders-in-jetpack-contact-form)

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/jetpack-plugin-editing-the-copy-of-the-comment-field-for-posts?replies=2

Answer (score 0):

The comment form is generated from another domain via the iframe. While I was accessing the `iframe` using jQuery `content()` it returned me `Permission denied to access.` It means the Jetpack is `Cross Site Scripting` protected and you cannot edit the placeholder.